# Inputing and reading realy long numbers over 200 characters using char* arr in C

Tags: arrays, c, char, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm stuck on an assignment I have to read from console really long number and then print it out using char* arr. Then I need to add and subtract number 1 array to number2 array. To be honest adding and subtracting I will probably deal on my own but I cannot figure out how to read those input characters, character by character and make while break after enter in console.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int subtract(const char* number1, const char* number2, char** result){
if(number1 == NULL || number2 == NULL){
        return 1;
    }
return 0;
}
int add(const char* number1, const char* number2, char** result) {
    if(number1 == NULL || number2 == NULL){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int input_check(int check, char* number) {
    if (check != 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }

}

int main()
{
    char* number1;
    //char* number2;
    //char** result;
    int check = 0;

    number1 = (char*)calloc(200,sizeof(char));
    //number2 = (char*)calloc(200, sizeof(char));
    //result = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * sizeof(char) * 400);
    if (number1 == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory");
        return 8;
    }
    
    printf("Input first num: ");
    
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        char retVal;
        scanf("%c", &retVal);
        if (retVal >= 48 || retVal <= 57 || retVal != '\0') {
            *(number1 + i) = retVal;
            if ((number1 + i) == NULL) {
                break;
            }
            printf("%d", atoi((number1 + i)));
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is there a maximum number of characters in the input numbers? Just use that for the arrays ... `char input1[MAXLEN + 1] = {0}, input2[MAXLEN + 1] = {0}, sum[MAXLEN + 2] = {0};`

Comment: No there is no limits of maximum number of characters

Comment: I think your ORs (`||`) need to be replaced with AND (`&&`) in your condition checking `retVal`. Also, a handy tip is that you don't have to use 48 and 57. You can just compare with `'0'` and `'9'`. Checking for a NUL character is also likely not useful, since an input line ends with a newline (`'\n'`) rather than a NUL (`'\0'`). Also, if your number is 200 characters, you'll need to allocate 201 so that there is a NUL terminator at the end.

Comment: You will also fix at least one bug and make your code more readable if you replace `*(number1 + i)` with `number1[i]`.

Comment: I can't replace ```*(number1 + i)``` because our checking platform will tell me I can't use such declarations as ```number1[i]```

Comment: That is... certainly an interesting constraint.

Comment: Instead of a loop to read character by character, why don't you use a single `fgets()` which will read a complete line (including EOL delimiter)?

Comment: Or at the very least, replace `scanf` with `getchar`.

Comment: I cannot use ```fgets()``` it is a second constrain, I did replace ```scanf``` but I do not have idea how to check if user inputs letters or other characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no limit on the numbers, you need to use dynamic memory allocation.

The straightforward (*brute-force*) way is to keep increasing the allocated size

```
char *input = calloc(1, 1); // space for '\0'
size_t len = 0;
for (;;) {
    int ch = getchar();
    if (ch != '\n') {
        input[len] = ch; // replace '\0' with ch
        len++;
        char *tmp = realloc(input, len + 1);
        if (tmp == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        input = tmp;
        input[len] = 0; // add '\0'
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
// use input and len
free(input);
```